# last index of C-style string in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, c-strings

I tried to write lastindexOf function for my C++ class. After I was trying for 2 weeks, I still can't get it working. 
At first , I was trying to follow the logic from this post: [CString find the last entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11983903/cstring-find-the-last-entry) , but since they use CString class instead of char class,I have no success to duplicate the code for char class. I also try the strstr, but I have no luck with that neither. I would appreciate any helps.
here is the code I have came up with so far :

#include

```
using namespace std;
int lastIndexOf(char *s, char target);
int main()
{
 char input[50];
 cin.getline(input, 50);
 char h = h;
 lastIndexOf(input, h);
 return 0; 
 }
 int lastIndexOf( char *s, char target)
 {   
int result = -1;

while (*s != '\0')
{
  if (*s == target ){
   return *s; 
 }}
 return result;
 }
```

Comment: You're looking for `strchr()`. And your error, by the way, is that you don't increment the loop counter of the `while` loop so it's going to be infinite.

Comment: For lastIndexOf(), strrchr() would probably be better.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
int lastIndexOf(const char * s, char target)
{
   int ret = -1;
   int curIdx = 0;
   while(s[curIdx] != '\0')
   {
      if (s[curIdx] == target) ret = curIdx;
      curIdx++;
   }
   return ret;
}
```