# Return index of last occurrence of a char in a constant array of chars

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, indexing, char

I need to return the last occurrence of a char in a const array of chars. So if I have a const array of chars that is ["helloe"] and the char index I need to return is "e", it will return the 5.

```
//s is a const array of chars that equals ["helloe"]
// c is the char "e"
// I need to return the index of the last occurrence of e which is 5
int reverse_find_character(const char s[], char c){
    std::vector<int> no;
    size_t bob = strlen(s);
    size_t i;
    for (i=bob;i>bob;i++){
       if (s[i]==c){
           no.push_back((int)i);

       }
   return *max_element(no.begin(),no.end());
}
```

Comment: A simpler plan is to return the first occurrence , but using reverse iterators

Comment: What is your problem/question ?

Comment: `size` would be a better name than `bob`.

Comment: Why do you need a vector if you only want to find one value?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11983903/cstring-find-the-last-entry

Answer (score 2):

```
std::vector<int> no;

// ...

no.push_back((int)i);
```

Why do you need a vector? You don't need a vector at all. You don't need to remember every occurrence of the searched character. You only need to find the last one.

```
for (i=bob;i>bob;i++){
```

This makes very little sense. Your intent seems to be to start scanning from the end of the string (`bob` is the string's length). Which would be a reasonable first start. But, if your intent is to start from the end of the string and work your way back to `i=0`, you expect `i` to be decremented, not incremented. Furthermore, the comparison `i>bob` again makes no sense. With the initial value of `i` being `bob`, the expression `i>bob` will evaluate to `false`, and this loop will never be executed.

Anyway, this whole thing is really much simpler than you think it is:

1. Start scanning the string, from start to finish.
2. Each time you see the character you are searching for, save its index in a variable.

Therefore, at the end of the scan, this variable will be the index of the last position of the character in your string, because you're scanning it from the beginning to the end.

In other words:

```
int reverse_find_character(const char s[], char c){
    int pos=-1;
    size_t i;

    for (i=0; s[i]; ++i)
       if (s[i] == c)
           pos = i;

    return pos;
}
```

P.S. You didn't ask about types, but it's more technically correct to use `ssize_t` instead of `int`s, in this context.

Comment: using `size_t` is acceptable too (`std::string` in fact does this)

Comment: just be aware that `size_t` blows up if you use it in a loop with `--i` for example down to 0 since it runs one more time and a negative `size_t` is creating some very bad stuff. Also what would an `auto` make of this?

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to loop backward from the end and stop on the first occurrence of your char:

```
int reverse_find_character(const char s[], char c){
    for (int i = strlen(s)-1; i>=0; --i)
        if (s[i] == c)
            return i;
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about `std::find` with a reverse iterator. Then use `std::distance` to get the index.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;    

int main()
{
    const char str[] = "helloe";

    auto it = std::find(crbegin(str), crend(str), 'e');

    cout << std::distance(cbegin(str), (it + 1).base()) << '\n';
}
```

Comment: This code assumes C++14 is used.  For earlier versions, you can use `std::reverse_iterator` directly, or maybe use `std::find_end()`.